# Is there any way to get username from USERID?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Code I'm using to get userid:

```
    user = update.message.from_user
    userid = user['id']
```

Is there any way to turn userid into username?

Comment: i believe it's possible with a userbot

Comment: what is that? Is it possible to implement that in my code? @Axeltherabbit

Comment: https://docs.pyrogram.org/

Comment: Can't find anything, could you help me @Axeltherabbit?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the full user available, you can just use `user.username`: [python-telegram-bot docs](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a6/telegram.user.html#telegram.User.username), [telegram docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user). If you only have the user id and not the full `User` object, you can query info about the user using `getChat`: [PTB docs](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a6/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.get_chat), [TG docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchat).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`